# Eslint rule to always put functions at the end?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Is there any way to configure eslint (ideally with `--fix`) to always put functions at the end?

```js
// Before/incorrect
function f() {
  return 5
}
const x = f()
function g() {
  function h() { return 6 }
  return h()
}
const y = g()

// After/correct
const x = f()
const y = g()
function f() { return 5 }
function g() {
  return h()
  function h() { return 6 }
}
```

See also: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15633

Comment: Why does `y` follow `f` in your desired output?

Comment: my bad fixed typo